# Fresh TypeScript Project with Cloud Function Packages Installed has Compiler Errors

Tags: typescript, firebase, compiler-errors, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I've started a new TypeScript project in *Visual Studio Code* that I want to use with Cloud Functions for Firebase service and I'm getting a ton of compiler errors.  I've looked far and wide to try and solve them as they appear to be breaking the Intelisense as well as adding errors to any of the TypeScript code I write myself.

I can reproduce the issues on a new project after installing just the tools and I'm now really confused as to what the issue is.

I have `firebase-tools` installed globally.

I start with an empty folder, first I create a `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Next I add the `tasks.json` file.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Then I run `firebase init functions` to init the project for working with the functions APIs.

The packaged installed from running this step are setup in a `packages.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~4.1.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

At this point, when I try to build the project, and let it run `tsc` I end up with a pile of errors, like Duplicate Identifier, and Interface `Server` cannot simultaneously extend types 'Server' and 'EventEmitter'.

[image: Sample of Compiler Errors]

After scowering Google for a while I can't figure out what the issue is.  I'm relatively new to TypeScript and I'm not 100% familiar with what everything is, and where everything goes but what it looks like is that there are conflicts because the types the `@types` and `typings` files are exporting are getting mixed up with either each other or something that is globally installed.

[image: List of Files with Compiler Errors]

I've tried using the exclude property in the `tsconfig.json` to exclude the `typings` directory, but that doesn't seem to work.

The closest ticket I've found to my issue is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10504) as part of the TypeScript project, but I'm not sure which module it is or where to point the path to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not sure if my lack of familiarity with TypeScript is the issue (i.e. a configuration problem) or it is a bug or something like that.

**Edit:**  I've updated nodejs and npm to versions 7.10.0 and 4.2.0 respectively.  I removed the packages and reinstalled them and now I have a slightly different set of errors.  The `node_modules` directory seems to have been flattened out.

The file that had errors in the changed.
[image: New set of files with errors]

But the same errors occurred.
[image: Same errors]

Comment: If you're using nodejs and npm and webpack or browserify, you should not have a typings directory in general and just use node_modules/@types. Also make sure you don't have that @types/core-js

Comment: Hi there, I'm using VS Code and I don't think I'm using browserify or webpack?  The directories came from when the dependencies were installed so I don't think I have any control over them.

Comment: sure you do, just delete them and remove the typings install command from the package.json file

Comment: I went through and removed the typings and update the respective project files and that broke some of the other TS files that depended on them.  The typings directories were only used for the base64url module.  It must be something else that is causing this issue.

The reason I said I don't think I have any control is if the package ever updated it would break my custom changes.

Comment: You could always just selectively uninstall the ones you don't need

Comment: I'm not sure what to remove since the only two main packages that are installed are `firebase-admin` and `firebase-functions`.  The other node modules that are there are part of those packages.

Comment: Looking over the errors more, it appears that there is a nested node_modules directory that is causing duplicates. What version of npm are you running?

Comment: I'm currently using version 2.15.9.

Comment: I just updated to node 7.10.0 and npm 4.2.0 and I still get the same build errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the same issue (with a myApp fresh project) doing:

```
npm remove typescript --save-dev && npm install typescript@2.1 --save-dev
```

I hope this helps